# Anaconda: Get packages with "lower equal package version" requirement

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I've been looking through the anaconda wiki and googled it but either my vocabulary is failing me or there is no such answer to my question.

I'm using Windows with Anaconda and want to check which installed packages require another package with a version to be *below* some number. I think I may have installed to many packages with such requirements and often conda wants to update some of these and when I want to update all packages again they are listed as being downgraded again.

Is there an easy way of getting the package names and the below requirements (where requirement is for example `matplotlib < 1.5`)?